# Substituting the values using $\int_a^b|\sin x|\,\mathrm{d}x=8$ and $\int_0^{a+b}|\cos x|\,\mathrm{d}x=9$

Tags: trigonometry

If
$$
\newcommand{\dx}{\,\mathrm{d}x}
\int_a^b|\sin x|\dx = 8 \quad\text{and}\quad\int_0^{a+b}|\cos x|\dx = 9
$$
then find the value of
$$(\tan a. \tan b)$$

For this type of question I am not able to open the values in modulus sign. I am not able to approach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\newcommand{\dx}{\,\mathrm{d}x}\int_{a}^{b} \vert\sin x\vert \dx = \int_{0}^{b-a} \vert\sin x \vert \dx$, because of periodicity and symmetry of $\vert\sin(\cdot)\vert$.

Since
$$
\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\vert\sin x\vert \dx = (-1)^k \big( \cos([k+1]\pi) - \cos(k\pi)\big) = 2
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{n\pi} \vert\sin x\vert \dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\vert\sin x\vert \dx = 2n,
$$
we have $b-a = 4\pi$.

A similar argument for $\int_0^{a+b} \vert\cos x\vert \dx$ yields $a+b = 4.5\pi$.

The rest is solving this linear system of equations.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^{1}|\sin(x)| dx \approx 0.92$ and  $\int_{0}^{2}|\sin(x)| dx \approx 1.41$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette you are right. However, for this exercise this doesn't change the solution.